# Need help running basic python selenium script that opens in chrome on android

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kivy

I have successfully deployed a test script, print("Hello World"), from my PC to my android using Kivy and Buildozer. This was done on a VM VirtualBox version of the latest version of Ubuntu. It works and that is great! Now, I want to test a web crawler using selenium, kivy and buildozer.

On [this page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android), it talks a little to the idea of it. If I change my main.py file that buildozer loads to the below script, it does appear to deploy and the Kivy app opens. But then it immediately shuts down. It doesn't open Chrome and it doesn't go to Google.com. I need help troubleshooting a solution to this. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/user123/KivyHelloWorld/chromedriver', options=options)
# Ubuntu location of webdriver for android
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

In the buildozer.spec I have updated the lines 37-39 to include selenium.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,selenium
```

After I made and save the changes to the main.py and buildozer.spec files I run this command in the terminal to deploy it:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```